# How to Filter Junk Features Automatically

Tags: regression, svm, feature-selection, weka

A data set that is used to build a regression model  might contain "junk" fields. For example if I want to build a model of house prices, the field *number of rooms* and the *size of the house* are correlated so the *number of rooms* field needs to be omitted.

Another example, when evaluating stock prices, the fields are *income* and *revenue* are correlated, but simply omitting one of them would remove significant information: instead the *revenue* field has to be transformed into *revenue/income* ratio.

How does junk data affects linear or support vector machine regressions and what are the standard approaches to deal with it automatically?

Comment: If "being correlated" with another predictor is a rule for omitting a predictor you will probably end up with single predictor models in most applications. It's more likely that you mean being **highly** correlated, but it's hard to automate intelligent choice and there aren't easy universal thresholds to identify that state. For example, a variable $x$ and its square $x^2$ might both be used to capture some nonlinearity, but the correlation between those two is usually very high.

Answer (score 1):

One common approach to de-correlation is [principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis).  In your example above "revenue" and "income" would be combined into a single component that would reflect their linear dependence.

The cool thing about PCA is you also get a second component that captures situations where revenue/income do not have the expected linear relationship.  (e.g. income is unusually low for a given revenue number).